# How can I get syntax highlighting for styled components template literals?

Tags: visual-studio-code, colors, template-literals

Using styled-components inside a react project, I am writing the following code.
In a video I'm following to code along, the instructors VS Code is applying color format to the template literal.

I'm using One Dark Pro theme and the template literal doesn't have any color format applied.
Is this intended or am I missing some settings?

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

const Button = styled.button`
  font: inherit;
  padding: 0.5rem 1.5rem;
  border: 1px solid #8b005d;
  color: white;
  background: #8b005d;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  cursor: pointer;
`
```

[Screenshot shows code inside template literal all green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IC5P9.png)

Since One Dark Pro is so popular, I assumed that it should supported.
Tried reinstalling the extension, but it didn't change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already, try installing the [`styled-components.vscode-styled-components`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=styled-components.vscode-styled-components) extension. From its docs:

> The styled-components extension adds highlighting and IntelliSense for styled-component template strings in JavaScript and TypeScript. See [plugin configuration](https://github.com/styled-components/typescript-styled-plugin#configuration) for information on configuring the linter and other language features.

Bonus info: If you want to get additional IntelliSense for styled components, set up the dedicated TypeScript plugin for styled components ([`typescript-plugin-styled-components`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-plugin-styled-components)).

Comment: That extension did the trick! Thank you so much